# angular openstreetmap directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/simple-example.html

Неre is the example I need.

http://tomaszdziurko.pl/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/navbar_angularjs1.png

But I need this map in Third page.

What should I put on the controller?

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider

    // route for the about page
        .when('/third', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/third.html',
            controller: 'thirdController'
        });

App.controller('thirdController', function ($scope) {
        angular.extend($scope, {
            defaults: {
                scrollWheelZoom: false
            }
        });
});
```

on the html I just set `<leafset></leafset>`

but it it wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've properly included the directive.

First:

include all the necessary scripts in the correct order:

```
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.1/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/angular-leaflet-directive.min.js"></script>
```

Second:

Include the CSS as well:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.1/leaflet.css">
```

Third:

Include the directive in your app dependencies:

```
var app = angular.module("demoapp", ['leaflet-directive']);
```

That third part is probably what you are missing, seeing as how it is not specifically documented on their site.  Please see the code for their simple example:

[angular-leaflet-directive - simple-example](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/blob/master/examples/simple-example.html)

Comment: I've added!
<script>
var App = angular.module('App', ['leaflet-directive']);
App.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$routeProvider
 .when('/', {
 templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
 controller: function ($scope) {}})
 .when('/about', {
 templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
 controller: function ($scope) {}});
 });
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="/"> home</a></li>
<li><a href="/about"> about</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>    
<div ng-view></div></body>
doesn't work
where about.html =<leaflet></leaflet>

Comment: I made a plunker to see if I could get the directive working. it seems that doing <leaflet></leaflet> by itself like the website says doesn't work.  You have to at a minimum add the height and width attributes. see my plunker here: [plunker - leaflet](http://plnkr.co/edit/CovUqGH0oHVnpxRWP59Y?p=preview).
Now, you may also have some issues with your use of routing, so I removed that from my plunker since it wasn't relevant to getting the leaflet directive working. Hope this helps.

Comment: it helps-I understand how add controllers,thanrs)
yeah,I had problem with route.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874926/angular-openstreetmap-with-routeprovider/20875736?noredirect=1#20875736
here is answer.